# SSL Sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, openssl

I want to secure comunication in my application using SSL. I am using *org.apache.commons.ssl* and OpenSSL. I have created key and crt like this (those are self signed for now):

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out szrr.crt -keyout szrr.key
openssl rsa -des3 -in szrr.key -out szrr.key.new
del szrr.key
move szrr.key.new szrr.key
```

So i have now key and cert which i use this way:

```
KeyMaterial km = new KeyMaterial(certChain, key, password);
SSLServer sslServer = new SSLServer();
sslServer.setKeyMaterial(km);
sslServer.addTrustMaterial(TrustMaterial.TRUST_ALL);
sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServer
                    .createServerSocket(serverPort);
```

certChain, key are paths to crt and key, password is just password :)

Now what else do I have to do to create SSLClient similar way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the example below:

```
SSLClient client = new SSLClient();
char[] pwd = "secret".toCharArray();

client.addTrustMaterial( TrustMaterial.DEFAULT );
client.addTrustMaterial( new TrustMaterial( "/path/to/self-signed.pem" ) );
client.addTrustMaterial( new KeyMaterial( "/path/to/keystore.jks", pwd ) );

client.setCheckHostname( true ); // default is "true" 
client.setCheckExpiry( true );   // default is "true" 
client.setCheckCRL( true );      // default is "true" 

// load a client certificate (max: 1 per SSLClient instance).
client.setKeyMaterial( new KeyMaterial( "/path/to/client.pfx", "secret".toCharArray() ) );
SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) client.createSocket( "www.mysite.com", 443 );
```

Comment: To be honest, I saw that example, however I am not sure what is going on there with those certs. Currently I have a self signed crt and key. I know I can generate pem, jks and whatever-else-i-want but isn't there any simpler way?

Comment: All that you need on the client is the truststore if your server is not authenticating the client. If it does then your client also needs its own certificate. But, for one way validation you just need the trust store and thats it. Just one client.addTrustMaterial( new TrustMaterial("path to truststore", pwd));